Same email domain set up in both Google and Office365
I have the following scenario:

Domain contoso.org is set in Google Workspace but MX is not (there are no email accounts in this domain)
Domain contoso.org is set in Office365 along with MX

We have another domain in Google Workspace in a separate account (contoso2.org) and it’s the only domain that cannot send emails to anything@contoso.org. I’m guessing Google is trying to route it internally (since it has that same domain).
Any ideas how to make Google disregard this domain that’s in it?
